Android Studio: "Unexpected Token" error with spinners/adapters
I am new to Android Studio. I am trying to create a very simple app to convert units.
I want to add a spinner (dropdown menu) for the user to select what kind of units they want to convert (eg: length, weight, etc.).
I followed along with a tutorial about how to create a spinner with multiple choices. Despite seemingly implementing everything correctly, I am getting an error message with the lines of code related to the "adapter" that is supposed to take an array of strings from my strings.xml file and assign them to the spinner.
Here is the code I wrote:
Spinner spinnerUnitTypes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_unit_types);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.unit_types, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinnerUnitTypes.setAdapter(adapter);

It's the last two lines (3+4) that produce errors.
LINE 3:
Hovering over "adapter" in line 3 produces an error message saying "Unexpected Token".
Hovering over "setDropDownViewResource" produces an error message saying "Unexpected Token. Cannot resolve symbol 'setDropDownViewResource'"
Hovering over "android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item" produces an error message saying "Unknown class: 'android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item'"
LINE 4:
Hovering over "spinnerUnitTypes" produces an error message saying "Unexpected token."
Hovering over "setAdapter" produces an error message saying "Unexpected token. Cannot resolve symbol 'setAdapter'".
Hovering over "adapter" produces an error message saying "Unknown class: 'adapter'".
Screenshot of code and imports
I tried some of the solutions to the 'unexpected token' error found on this post but they did not resolve the issue.

All of that code should be inside of a method, such as onCreate() of your activity.

That is not really a "tutorial" IMHO, in that it only shows some code snippets.
In this case, they are expecting those four lines of code to reside in a method, such as onCreate() of your activity. In Java, you cannot have statements like lines 3-4 in arbitrary locations, and the vast majority of the time, they are in a method.

Thank you. I added it to OnCreate() and the errors went away.
